# Como Separar dados em dicionario a partir de um .txt (Python)

Tags: python, dicionário

Tenho um arquivo de texto (anexo.txt), que tenho a armazenar em um dicionário, com Nome como chave e telefone, valor. o arquivo tem as seguintes informações:

```
--- nome telefone ---
Ailton-1197765445 Josefa-2178655434
```

Usei o seguinte código:

```
ref_files = open("anexo.txt", "r")
for linha in ref_files:
    valos = linha.split()
    print(valos[0],valos[:0],valos[1:])

ref_files.close()
```

mas ele retorna os valores assim:
**Ailton-1197765445 [] ['Josefa-2178655434']**

Criei o dicionário mas o retorno eh o mesmo:

```
dic = { k.split()[0]:k.split()[1:] for k in ref_files.readlines() }
```

alguém poderia ajudar-me com isso?
Agradecido.

Comment: É importante notar que quando você usa *slicers* em uma lista, tais como está fazendo quando faz `[1:]`, você obtém **uma lista** como resultado.

Comment: São sempre dois nomes por linha ou podem haver mais? A primeira linha do arquivo, `--- nome telefone ---`, também está no arquivo ou só colocou na pergunta para exemplificar?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss são sempre dois nomes por linha, e a primeira linha também está no arquivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def monta_dicionario(caminho=None):
    with open(caminho, "r") as anexo:
        dic = {}
        for linha in  anexo.readlines()[1:]:
            nomes = linha.split(" ")
            for nome_tel in nomes:
                val = nome_tel.split('-')
                dic[val[0]] = val[1]

    return dic

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dic = monta_dicionario('./anexo.txt')
    print(dic)
```

Comment: Obrigado! ta tudo como queria, obrigado